# Wordpress Rest API V2: Return number of post per page via endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-api

How to output custom post type post per page via **wp rest api v2** endpoints?

I know i could use this:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/products?filter[post_per_page]=2
```

But i would like to implement it via endpoints changing the url is not an option at this time for me.